# Multiply values depending on values of certains columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication

I have two data base, df and cf. I want to multiply each value of A in df by each coefficient in cf depending on the value of B and C in table df.

For example
  row 2 in df A= 20 B= 4 and C= 2 so the correct coefficient is 0.3, 
the result is 20*0.3 = 6

There is a simple way to do that in R!?

Thanks in advance!!

```
 df
    A  B  C
   20  4  2
   30  4  5
   35  2  2
   24  3  3
   43  2  1


   cf
      C
 B/C  1   2   3   4   5
 1   0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.7
 2   0.1 0.5 0.3 0.3 0.4
 3   0.9 0.1 0.6 0.6 0.8
 4   0.7 0.3 0.7 0.4 0.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution with `apply`:

```
#iterate over df's rows
apply(df, 1, function(x) {

 x[1] * cf[x[2], x[3]]

})
#[1]  6.0 18.0 17.5 14.4  4.3
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by characters. You wouldn't be able to multiply two strings, but the concept above works for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this vectorized:

```
df[,1] * cf[as.matrix(df[,2:3])]

#[1]  6.0 18.0 17.5 14.4  4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and a vectorised function:

```
df = read.table(text = "
                A  B  C
                20  4  2
                30  4  5
                35  2  2
                24  3  3
                43  2  1
                ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

cf = read.table(text = "
                0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.7
                0.1 0.5 0.3 0.3 0.4
                0.9 0.1 0.6 0.6 0.8
                0.7 0.3 0.7 0.4 0.6
                ")

library(dplyr)

# function to get the correct element of cf
# vectorised version
f = function(x,y) cf[x,y]
f = Vectorize(f)

df %>%
  mutate(val = f(B,C),
         result = val * A)

#    A B C val result
# 1 20 4 2 0.3    6.0
# 2 30 4 5 0.6   18.0
# 3 35 2 2 0.5   17.5
# 4 24 3 3 0.6   14.4
# 5 43 2 1 0.1    4.3
```

The final dataset has both `result` and `val` in order to check which value from `cf` was used each time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got a question, why do you transform the data to a table? We have it as data frame and we can not transform it as a table.

Comment: Both `df` and `cf` are dataframes. The command to read them is `read.table` but they are not tables.